# Alteryx only pulls 1 million rows from Snowflake, max

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alteryx

I'm using Alteryx workflows to spool some data from Snowflake.
The problem is that for some reason, Alteryx only pulls 1 million records, tops.

**The input data tool has no max records marked**, it should pull as much as it finds.

This is odd since I thought Alteryx was pretty much meant to be used with very large data sets. Is there some special configuration one needs to apply to pull over million records or is it just something that alteryx cannot do?

I looked in alteryx resources and couldn't find anything mentioning the issues. I don't know where to begin from.

Comment: there is a 1 million rows limit from the WebUI, the ODBC driver (released in 2014) can pull more rows that 1m. If you look at the query in the WebUI History page what client is it connecting via? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2014-12.html

Comment: I am not using web UI, I'm using alteryx designer desktop and establishing the connection through ODBC. I think this might be from snowflake's side

Comment: yes, I am just telling you "one of the methods of interacting is limited, but the ODBC is supposed to not be limited". and "from the webui if you are admin, you can check what client a query was run by, to see if that cleint has limits"